# Mobile push received for 2 different flavors

Tags: android, push-notification, android-productflavors

I've got android application with 2 different flavors:

```
        first {
            applicationId 'com.test.first'
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'First'
            resValue 'string', 'host', 'app.first.com'
            resValue 'string', 'app_id', '3'
            resValue 'string', 'auth_client_id', 'xxx'
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
        second {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.second
            applicationId 'com.test.second'
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Second'
            resValue 'string', 'host', 'app.second.com'
            resValue 'string', 'app_id', '2'
            resValue 'string', 'auth_client_id', 'xxx'
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
        }
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test">
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <application>
         <receiver
            android:name="com.test.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I receiving push notifications for both flavors correctly. Problem is, that if I have both flavors installed in my phone, I receive 2 same pushes for both flavors.

It seems that application does not recognize for which flavor push belongs. Maybe somebody had the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried with `android:name="${applicationId}.GcmBroadcastReceiver"` for the receiver name (supposing you have 2 differents implementations)?

Comment: Then I get 'Unresolved class' error. I have 1 package named com.test and all code shared for both flavors.

Comment: Maybe your problem is caused by using the same `google-services.json` file, you should register your second flavor, download the json file and provide a different folder for your app where store the different `google-services.json`

Comment: I've got 2 google-services.json files. Both located in different folders for each flavor. And both are different.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your problem like..

Your fcm/gcm project package name is `"com.test"`
and then your android app having two flavours 
namly

**1. first with applicationId 'com.test.first'**

**2. second with applicationId 'com.test.second'**

so, If you are and any push it will receive in both flavors because your both `flavors contain com.test`, So you could be manage or handle manually... like

send your application id or any flavor identification token with a push, then you have to manage that in after receiving a push.

**for example**

send push for first flavor(In your first app)

```
if(data.first_flavor_token)
{
   //Create and show your push here
}
```

send push for second flavor(In your second app)

```
if(data.second_flavor_token)
{
   //Create and show your push here
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way? Because it does not seems very solid to me. Or if I want have 2 different apps (using different flavors) is not a good approach?

Comment: I am working with 17 flavors, now i am handle like that only...., i dont know any other solution is possible..